# Using "click" binding in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout , trying to learn Click binding in Knockout.

My example code is

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: addEmp('fnameX', 'lnameX')">Add one more</button>
<ul data-bind="foreach: employees">
<li>
<span data-bind="text: fname"> </span> <span data-bind="text: lname"> </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// model
function employee(fname, lname) {
    this.fname = ko.observable(fname);
    this.lname = ko.observable(lname);
}

// view model

var vm = {
    company: ko.observable('Company Name'),
    employees: ko.observableArray(),
    addEmp: function (fname, lname) {
        this.employees.push(new employee(fname, lname));

    }
};


// adding employees to array
vm.addEmp('fname1', 'lname1');
vm.addEmp('fname2', 'lname2');


//binding
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**Out I was Expecting :**

2 records should be displayed , and when user clicks "Add one more" , a new record should get added to viewmodel , and it should get reflected in my view.

**But , the actual Output is :**

3 records are getting displayed initially , and when user clicks "Add one more" , NO record is getting added to viewmodel , and not getting reflected in the view.

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Rama_Kishore/AGycj/

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No , am not getting any error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout passes some context parameters to the function called with the click binding, so your parameters are confusing it. In order to call a function with parameters directly within the binding, wrap it in an outer function, like this:

```
<button data-bind="click: function() { addEmp('fnameX', 'lnameX') }">Add one more</button>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5S3r/)

**Edit:** knockout documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) explains this in the second code example under "note 2"

Comment: @user2693545 Great! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so it drops out of the Unanswered list.